# Averaging Python Pandas Date format

Tags: python, pandas, date, time, average

I have some data like the format below:

```
2016-06-02 22:00:00 
2016-06-02 22:00:01 
2016-06-02 22:00:01 
2016-06-02 22:00:02 
2016-06-02 22:00:02
```

This data is in a Pandas DataFrame, and what I want is to averagint it by days, like this:

```
2016-06-2  I 300
```

So I would like to calculate how many items, was averaged by this.

Any ideas? I tried to use value_counts, but it gave a false result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df = df['date'].dt.date.value_counts()
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).size()
```